# Getting script to return a link in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I found a script that's used to extract saved articles from Feedly (by running it inside Chrome's Inspect Element console), but I'd like to tweak it a bit for my needs. I'm not a developer or anything like that so I'd appreciate it if someone could help!

Here's part of the script:

```
json = ""
function copyToClipboard() {
// Loop through the DOM, grabbing the information from each bookmark
map = jQuery("#section0_column0 div.u0Entry.quicklisted").map(function(i, el) {
    var $el = jQuery(el);
    var regex = /published:(.*)\ --/i;
    return {
        title: $el.data("title"),
        url: $el.data("alternate-link"),
        time: regex.exec($el.find("div.lastModified span").attr("title"))[1]
    };
}).get(); // Convert jQuery object into an array

// Convert to a nicely indented JSON string
json = JSON.stringify(map, undefined, 2)
```

Here's an example of what it returns:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Blog post headline",
    "url": "http://urlofblogpost.com/article",
    "time": "Tue, 10 Dec 2014 21:00:00 GMT"
  },
  {
    "title": "Blog post2 headline",
    "url": "http://urlofblogpost.com/article2",
    "time": "Tue, 10 Dec 2014 21:00:00 GMT"
  },
]
```

Here's what I'd like it to return:

```
<a href="http://urlofblogpost.com/article">Blog post headline</a>
<a href="http://urlofblogpost.com/article2">Blog post2 headline</a>
```

The most I could do on my own was delete the "time" part from the script, remove the brackets, and isolate the titles and URLs (using a text editor):

```
Blog post headline
http://urlofblogpost.com/article
```

Is there any way to change the script to get it in links?

Comment: So, you want to return the url in your json into your a href like that or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Iterate through the json:

Javascript:

```
function copyToClipboard() {
// Loop through the DOM, grabbing the information from each bookmark
map = jQuery("#section0_column0 div.u0Entry.quicklisted").map(function(i, el) {
    var $el = jQuery(el);
    var regex = /published:(.*)\ --/i;
    return {
        title: $el.data("title"),
        url: $el.data("alternate-link"),
        time: regex.exec($el.find("div.lastModified span").attr("title"))[1]
    };
}).get(); // Convert jQuery object into an array

var theLink = '';
$.each(yourJson, function(k,v){ 
   theLink +=  "<a href=" + v.url + " >" + v.title + " </a>, \n";
}); 

window.prompt('my link', theLink);
```

I create js fiddle for you play: http://jsfiddle.net/reptildarat/GG5BP/4/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what to do with that. Is that something I do after using the script I have? (Plug it in your script in jsfiddle?)

Comment: Depend on what you want from the output, do you want it still like JSON or html?

Comment: I want the JSON script to output it as HTML instead of the example I showed

Comment: i update my fiddle link, you can check it again. and play with it, update it on fiddle if you still confuse.

Comment: Thanks! But if it's in jsfiddle, I can't copy the html lol. Could you change the original script so it turns to html links? No need for the bullets if it's easier.

Comment: do you want it to go to automaticall copy to your clipboard?

Comment: Yes exactly, just in the script

Comment: check my update, because copy to clipboard is different on 1 browser and another, so i prompt it with dialog, you can copy it with ctrl+c or command+c

Comment: I'm getting an error, about unexpected end when running. Here's the whole script: http://jsfiddle.net/9kVWr/

Comment: paste your html on jsfiddle, it will not working if there's no html in that.

Comment: Do you mean in the jsfiddle you posted? So it won't work directly from the script I posted if it's fixed?

Comment: just put your complete html with the javascript in jsfiddle that you create. in yours or mine.